# How do I serve multiple domains on the same port with nginx

Tags: nginx

For development, I'd like to serve multiple projects on different local domains, all on port 80. In my hosts file I direct local.example.com to localhost, same for local.example2.com.

Now I'm trying to convince nginx to serve the example resources for the one url, and the example2 resources for the other.

I've read the nginx documentation and [this blog post](http://blog.donaldderek.com/2013/08/cf-i-configure-your-staging-machine-with-node-js-and-nginx/). But I think I must be missing something.

I've added to my nginx.conf:

```
include /Users/iwein/Sites/conf/*.conf;
```

Then in sites I add configuration like `example.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name local.example.com;
…
```

and `example2.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name local.example2.com;
…
```

Now the weird thing is that nginx seems to load the alphabetically first config, but on the second url, it serves the resources from the first server definition too. Nginx seems to totally ignore the server_name. How should I configure for this use case?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that if you use only one separator in the domain name (e.g. example1.local), it works just fine. I didn't further pursue this, because I have better things to do, but it's odd.

Comment: did you reload the nginx config after creating those files? cause they seem to be correct.

Comment: Yes, I did @MohammadAbuShady. Several times

Comment: well the second guess is that the URL you are requesting isn't matching either `server_name`s or matching the wrong one, or maybe you have another server that matches the same request? and it's hit first before this one.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I checked that. The urls in my hosts file were copied into the conf files, so I can't see how they could be different. I'll start from a clean slate tomorrow (no angry coding for me)

Comment: I am having the same problem today, precisely. Any resolution?

Comment: In case it helps: I had directives like ``server_name example.com``. Changing them to ``server_name www.example.com`` fixed my problem. (Let me be the first to say that I don't really know what I'm doing in this area -- just sharing this in case it helps.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment anyway @DanAllan you'll probably help a poor lost soul with it one day. Not me unfortunately :)

Comment: @DanAllan I've had a similar resolution to the problem. I'm hoping someone figures it out for real at some point.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, nginx doesn't like the format of my server names. If I remove the 'local' subdomain it seems to work much better. I'm now working with `example.dev` and `example2.dev` and the problem is gone.